# kubectl get services with count of actively running pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How can I list all Kubernetes services along with the number of active pods associated with each service?

Currently, I can list all services with:
`kubectl get services`

I would like to add one additional column to the output, which lists active pod count for each service.

Comment: you want to look at the endpoint list of the service. Below answer doesnt really answer your question. Its dodging it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service is basically a load balancer over a deployment (and a deployment is a replica set of multiple pods).  So, chances are you want to be listing the deployments instead of the services in this case.  Services and deployments are loosely coupled via tags, so there probably isn't a great way to go from services to pods directly.

I recommend `kubectl get deploy -A` to view all deployments and their pod counts in all namespaces in this case.

Example output from the `kube-system` namespace in our cluster (since it's not sensitive in any way)...

```
NAMESPACE                        NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system                      cluster-autoscaler-aws-cluster-autoscaler   1/1     1            1           231d
kube-system                      coredns                                     2/2     2            2           231d
kube-system                      ebs-csi-controller                          2/2     2            2           231d
kube-system                      efs-csi-controller                          2/2     2            2           231d
kube-system                      metrics-server                              1/1     1            1           231d
```